# Hadoop standalone mode not starting at the local machine have permission issues

Tags: hadoop, ssh, permissions

I am not able to figure out what the problem is, I have checked all the links available for the problem and tried but still the same problem.
Please need help as the sandbox available needs higher configuration like more RAM.

```
hstart
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as adityaverma 
in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: adityaverma@localhost: Permission denied 
(publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting datanodes
localhost: adityaverma@localhost: Permission denied 
(publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting secondary namenodes [Adityas-MacBook-Pro.local]
Adityas-MacBook-Pro.local: adityaverma@adityas-macbook-pro.local: 
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
2018-05-30 11:07:03,084 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load 
 native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes    
where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: adityaverma@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Answer (score 0):

This error typically means you failed to setup passwordless SSH. For example, the same error should happen with `ssh localhost`, and it should not prompt for a password

Check the Hadoop documentation again on SSH key generation and add it to your authorized keys file

I might suggest setting up a virtual machine anyway (for example, using Vagrant) if the sandbox requires too many resources. The Hortonworks&Cloudrea installation docs are fairly detailed to install a cluster from scratch
This way, Hadoop isn't cluttering your Mac's hard drive and a Linux server will closer match Hadoop installations running in production environments

Comment: I see, okay, I actually did go through the documentation pretty carefully and ssh localhost should ask for a password but ill check it again. I mean documentation says it should do something like this and it exactly did that.  after typing ssh.

Comment: I will look more into vagrant as I have no clue about it. I mostly have used oracle virtual box. I will check for installation docs as well. Thanks I will get back to you if I have more issues may be you can help more, but appreciate your advice

Comment: Ssh should **not** ask for a password. Vagrant uses VirtualBox, but the OS is pre-installed based on the settings you use. and usually just a terminal. But if you look over the Vagrant provisioning documentation, you can setup scripts (or find Hadoop examples on Github, or use Puppet/Ansible, probably) that'll setup a mini sandbox for you automatically

Comment: I see okay sounds cool. I think I am going to stay busy this weekend with all this information you gave me. thanks. Will ask for more if not satisfied.